# crypto, node 6 return different hash than node4

Tags: node.js, cryptography

A upgrade nodeJS from 4.2.6 to 6.9.1 and crypto HMAC produce different output.
For example:
node 4.2.6:

```
crypto.createHmac('sha512', crypto_key_bytes).update(crypto_text).digest('hex')
.toUpperCase()
```

=>`20404FCB6D86CDF0E38002DD8BC36596C2882EB48433C074F9DDC2F1F6D47748E1F26E062E2D17671C18B87FFEE1C72576B48CFA9A61AF447A2F4C1B06316616` **is OK**.

node 6.9.1:

```
crypto.createHmac('sha512',crypto_key_bytes).update(crypto_text)
.digest('hex').toUpperCase();
```

or

```
crypto.createHmac('sha512',crypto_key_bytes2).update(crypto_text,'binary')
.digest('hex').toUpperCase();
```

or

```
crypto.createHmac('sha512',crypto_key_bytes2)
.update(crypto_text,'utf-8').digest('hex').toUpperCase();<code
```

=>`1D974668D0CB06B87C9645CF92161358951B224798015BAEE5A4BEDC54E88159E5082C6E3BB1D8612C904C33F9A80A88642ECB99B69B7BBDC5EC633119169DBE` **is NOT OK**

Do you have an idea ?
Thank you !

Comment: It's extremely likely that the difference is in the encoding of the input bytes (either the key or the input of the update method). It could even be that this is due to the encoding of the JavaScript source. Whenever possible, make the encoding of the characters to bytes *explicit*.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the problem you have is in the data, not the Node.js HMAC implementation.

I did a quick test with 4.2.6 and 6.9.1 and they do produce identical 'sha512' HMACs indeed.

**Code**

```js
var  crypto = require('crypto');
console.log(
    crypto.createHmac('sha512',"key").update("text").digest('hex').toUpperCase()
);
```

**Output**

```bash
./node --version
4.2.6 

./nodejs hmac
B585312ACDD38EC13F13BB4CBA35A75473F32B6AE4A0303926815BD43D7A2631516B2B031F34D89EDA853E948D5057DE54A880C16697242DBE6A1AD994BC4E5D

./node --version
v6.9.1

./nodejs hmac
B585312ACDD38EC13F13BB4CBA35A75473F32B6AE4A0303926815BD43D7A2631516B2B031F34D89EDA853E948D5057DE54A880C16697242DBE6A1AD994BC4E5D
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem result from the function :

> `for(var k=0 ; k < crypto_key.length-1 ; k+=2){
>       tmp = parseInt(crypto_key.substr(k, 2), 16);
>       crypto_key_bytes.push(tmp);
>   }`

correct by :

```
for(var k=0 ; k < crypto_key.length-1 ; k+=2){
tmp = parseInt(crypto_key.substr(k, 2), 16);
if (tmp>128) {
tmp = tmp-256;
}
crypto_key_bytes.push(tmp);
}`
```

The fonction parseInt() change from NodeJS 4.2.6 to 6.9.1..

Comment: OMG, that's a horrible way of handling API changes. They should just have added another function.